# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; ....." ...INNER JOIN"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, inner-join

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(IPD_Admit_Register_Det.BID) AS BID, 
  Bed_WardList.WID, Bed_FloorList.FID 
FROM 
  Bed_BedList 
  INNER JOIN shift_last_bed 
    INNER JOIN IPD_Admit_Register_Det 
      ON shift_last_bed.IPDid = IPD_Admit_Register_Det.IPDid 
      AND shift_last_bed.IDPdid = IPD_Admit_Register_Det.IPDdid 
    ON Bed_BedList.BID = IPD_Admit_Register_Det.BID 
  INNER JOIN Bed_FloorList 
    INNER JOIN Bed_WardList 
      ON Bed_FloorList.FID = Bed_WardList.FID 
    ON Bed_BedList.WID = Bed_WardList.WID
GROUP BY 
  IPD_Admit_Register_Det.BID, 
  Bed_WardList.WID, 
  Bed_FloorList.FID
```

above query is execute successfully in mssql server 2008 but when same doing in MySql using phpMyAdmin it throws error like

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'ON Bed_BedList.BID = IPD_Admit_Register_Det.BID INNER JOIN
> Bed_FloorList INNER J' at line 5

Comment: what is unclear in the message you are **reading**?

Comment: T-SQL and MySQL syntax are not necessarily the same. You can check in the manual. If I had to guess I'd say MySQL doesn't like those nested joins

Comment: This works in MS SQL? Really? You got your JOIN and ON clauses mixed up, shaken and stirred

Comment: @OcasoProtal yes mate, this query execute in MSSql not in mysql why??

Comment: As @ADyson said: Get rid of the nested joins

Comment: It's impossibly weird to group by the thing your counting, regardless of rdbms

Comment: Actually I'm bit confused plz guys help to rid of that Nested Joins

Comment: Do one thing. Please share table structures for all your table and mention what you actually want to get as an output. People can help you get your desired output with possibly simple query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys Appreciate your help! finally I got proper query as below

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(IPD_Admit_Register_Det.BID) AS BID, 
  Bed_WardList.WID, Bed_FloorList.FID 
FROM
  shift_last_bed,
  IPD_Admit_Register_Det,
  Bed_BedList,
  Bed_FloorList,
  Bed_WardList 
WHERE 
  (shift_last_bed.IPDid = IPD_Admit_Register_Det.IPDid) 
  AND (shift_last_bed.IPDdid = IPD_Admit_Register_Det.IPDdid)
  AND (Bed_BedList.BID = IPD_Admit_Register_Det.BID) 
  AND (Bed_FloorList.FID = Bed_WardList.FID)
  AND (Bed_BedList.WID = Bed_WardList.WID)
GROUP BY 
  IPD_Admit_Register_Det.BID, 
  Bed_WardList.WID, 
  Bed_FloorList.FID
```

Comment: IMO you'd still be better using inner joins rather than WHERE criteria, just not nested ones like you had above. But if this works and is quick enough then it's a valid solution